# Logical Grouping of content (layout) without using Tables

Tags: html, layout

I am new to web-designing styles and css. I read that usage of tables for layout is a bad practice. Hence I tried to create this layout using `<br\>` , `div` and `float`.

[image]

**Problem :** 
   Once, `<br\>` is applied, I can't render the upper part, (similar to once `\n` is printed in console, we cant go to the upper line).

So, could any one provide an alternative way of designing the page, without using `<table>` and `<br>` tags.

Comment: have you tried define `width` for `parent` and apply `display block` to child.?

Comment: If you're eager to learn the details of html and css then my following suggestion will be of no use, but if you just want to get a layout quickly then Twitter bootstrap is great for these kinds of layouts.

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar **I new to using styles and css**. I know only basics like tables,divs,textboxes etc.. That's the problem. Could you suggest some best links to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple example for doing so,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>StackOverFlow</title>
    <style type="text/css">

        .content{
            width:150px;
            height:100px;
            border:1px solid blue;
        }
        .content .text{
            display:block;
            border:1px solid red;
        }   
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="content">

        <div class="text">
            text here
        </div>

        <div class="text">
            another text here
        </div>

        <div class="text">
            yet another text here
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Code Explanation**

What i did is wrap `text` `div` inside `content` parent `div` and assign fixed width and height to parent div.

Now for `child` `div` i just used `display:block` and see the result. You do not need to use `<br/>` `display:block;` will do it for you.

Now what is the meaning of **display:block;** so it just tell browser to allow that particular `DOM` to take whole width of the parent `div`.

Comment: Here's your code http://jsfiddle.net/ck2MH/ what I want is "Another text here must be displayed on the right of the text here" but here it is displayed in the bottom

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT you have used br tag...why is that.??

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT if i am not wrong you want something like **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/ck2MH/3/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nATty/ I got this, which is exactly I want. I got this link by Alicia's (The volunteer's answer below) link

Comment: Thank you, now I understood quite basics. Like we could make some divs and make it to float by sharing the entire screen width could help.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT well that great you find code...but make sure you understand it properly...Happy Coding

Comment: well this is just beginning...there are other ways to do similar task in more complex way...you must take a look at `position` property which is most confusing but more more highly important.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a perfect example usage of a [grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).

Without using a grid system, you can just use `float: left` for each of the div and it should be OK.

Comment: Yep, but he mentioned it in his question, so I suppose he has already tried using it. But yes Twitter Bootstrap grid system is not the easier thing to learn for a new comer...

Answer (score 1):

By adding css to DIV's you can get some great layouts (i.e the three column style you're looking for here)  , try this aticle to get you started:
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3642151/CSS-Layouts-Without-Tables.htm